# Why do ICs often have multiples of the same configuration, with different part numbers?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet

Take the SN54AHC125/SN74AHC125 tri-state quad buffer, for example. Data sheet is here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahc125.pdf

Refer to page 7, and you will see this (snippet):

[image]

[Click here for a larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2r2m.png)

SN74AHC125DGVR, SN74AHC125DGVRE4, and SN74AHC125DGVRG4 (the TVSOP entries; middle of image) have the same properties according to that chart. What's even weirder is that chips with the same properties, from the same manufacturer, might cost different! I looked through the datasheet to see if it had anything to do with packaging, but I still couldn't find anything.

So why do multiple part numbers exist that reference the same part/configuration?

**Real example**

The reason I actually asked this question is that I'm interested in buying a small-ish quantity of said buffer chip. I want [this one](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?qs=pdM4geFiyZQ3d9h4LyQ5fw==), but I also see [a seemingly identical chip](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?qs=pdM4geFiyZQ7gqQzOEfS6Q==) (with the addition of G4 at the end of the part number) for a few cents cheaper. I thought *there must be a reason it's cheaper*, but I (obviously) couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Silicon revision?

Comment: I was thinking it might have to do with previous versions of the chip, but why wouldn't they just list previous versions in a separate section to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This may help](http://focus.ti.com/quality/docs/gencontent.tsp?templateId=5909&navigationId=11753&contentId=5055), from my reading the E4 or G4 designation seems to be based on the RoHS information; E4 and G4 are basically the same but the E values are used for JEDEC marking while the G values are used for TI-Green marking.

As for the pricing I can only speculate that Texas Instruments would prefer to sell one part (the G4 part in this case) over the other options.

Comment: Ok, great. Then for my uses I can go with the cheaper part. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The first column in that table is "orderable device", which indicates that different codes won't refer to functional differences, but rather finishing and packaging.

From [this document](http://focus.ti.com/pdfs/logic/Environmentally_Friendly_Solutions.pdf):

> SN74LS00D Standard part number
>   SN74LS00DE4 Pb-Free + NiPdAu part number
>   SN74LS00DG4 Pb-Free + NiPdAu + ‘green’ mold compound part number

That's also what timrorr refers to. Other differences in ordering codes may refer not just to the device package, but also how parts are delivered.

[image]

Here an "R" is appended to the ordering code to indicate "Tape and Reel" packaging instead of "Tube".