# What are the meanings of IC's suffixes?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic

What are the meanings of IC's suffixes? For a example, [CD4511BE](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4511b.pdf)? What is the meaning of BE? What are the other suffixes?

Comment: Also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35013/why-do-ics-often-have-multiples-of-the-same-configuration-with-different-part-n

Answer (score 6):

Every manufacturer has a different set of suffixes they add to their part numbers.

Most often they designate the package (SOIC, QFN, ...). Sometimes there's a code for whether the part is lead-free. And sometimes there's a code indicating how quantities of the part are packaged for shipping (usually tape & reel, but some parts might be available on different sized reels).

For analog parts, it's also common to have suffixes (typically 'A', 'B', etc.) designating different precision parts (for example a 1% voltage reference vs a 2% reference), different voltage settings, etc.

You'll need to check your datasheet to see exactly what suffixes are used for your part and what they mean. For your part, this information is on page 6 of the datasheet:

[image]

Comment: The Photon: 9 Seconds Ahead (sounds like a movie title!)

Comment: @ThePhoton can't you give direct mean of BE ? Like these 
74Fxx: means FAST

74LSXX: means LOW SHOTKY

74HCXX: means HIGH CMOS

Comment: @iNdra The answer is in the first line of the table in my answer. It's a part in a PDIP package with lead-free finish.

Comment: @iNdra Well, B  is part of the part number "CD4511B". E refers to the packaging PDIP.

Answer (score 4):

It differs by device and manufacturer. *Generally* suffixes indicate various options for the device, such as packaging options. (Through hole, surface mount, etc.) But you will just as often find that suffixes denote all sorts of options like frequency, power requirements, whether sleep mode is available, lead-free, RoHS, and so forth.

Check the datasheet, it will almost always inform you what the prefixes and suffixes mean. Look for the packaging options section, but there might be other charts which also involve the part suffixes.

In the case of the CD4511B specifically, the "B" is actually part of the base part name. It's a BCD to 7-segment latch decoder. I'm not sure what the "B" means, but you'll notice it's at the top of the datasheet for the part family.

On page 1, most suffixes are explained:

> The CD4511B types are supplied in 16-lead hermetic dual-in-line ceramic packages (F3A suffix), **16-lead dual-in-line plastic packages (E suffix)**, 16-lead small-outline packages (NSR suffix), and 16-lead thin shrink small-outline packages (PW and PWR suffixes).

Comment: can't you give me direct mean of BE ? Like these  
74Fxx: means FAST

74LSXX: means LOW SHOTKY

74HCXX: means HIGH CMOS

Comment: @iNdra: Could you at least *pretend* to read the answer?

Comment: IIRC 'B' is the buffered CMOS series. Long ago there were unbuffered versions of most CD4xxx chips. For certain (mis) uses (eg. using a port as a linear amplifier) only the unbuffered versions will do.